# Tool to track GDI Handle Leaks

Tags: windows, memory-leaks, debugging

An application has GDI Leaks, which I detected with [NirSoft GDIView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/gdi_handles.html). Now that I know there is a GDI Handle leak, I need a more professional tool with the following properties:

- works on Windows 7 and higher
- has 32 and 64 bit support
- records GDI handle leaks with call stack
- costs less than 500 €
- has prices available on the website, not on request
- has a GUI to start tracking, stop tracking and selecting the target application

I used to know BoundsChecker, but that is outdated and seems to be integrated into [Micro Focus DevPartner](https://www.microfocus.com/products/devpartner) for which the price is on request.

I have tried:

- [GDIDebug (SourceForge)](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ideatester/files/gdidebug/), but it was last updated in 2005 and either it does not work any more (perhaps due to 64 bit) or I'm just too stupid to use it.
- [LeakMon (CodeProject)](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/150463/leakmon-track-handle-leak-gdi-leak-and-memory-leak), but after the link to Google drive, it tells me that I'm not allowed to download infected files.
- [Rohitab API Monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor), which I used with a [list of methods](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/175591/leakmon-part-2-under-the-hood.aspx). This basically works, but it does not associate the creation and the deletion of GDI objects with each other, so I can't ditinguish between a leak from a non-leak